# Is there any way to change the Label at Lightning Experience in Aura Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, developer-edition

I created an aura component to override View Action in Account.

I want customize the label for Account tab, show like this format Account: {Account Name}. Please take a look follow image.

[image]

May I ask if you guys any idea how to implement feature? If can please share demo code or document to you.

Comment: You can rename the standard objects and field labels from `Rename Tabs and Labels` in setup.

Comment: If you are looking for static renaming then the above comment answers this, if not then by any chance if you are using a console navigation then you can use console api to set tab name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is console please go through below documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_setTabLabel.htm

Please let me know if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the Standard Object and Field Labels via Rename Tabs and Labels. Please go through below documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_rename.htm&type=0.

Please let me know if it is helpful.